# Classes and methods in Python (methods and attributes separated by definitions)

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, initialization

What is wrong with the code?

```
from pyaudio import *

class sphinx():
    def __init__(self, samprate=16000):
        self.recorder(samprate)

    def recorder(self, samprate):
        audio = PyAudio()
        recorder = audio.open(rate=samprate, channels=1, format=paInt16, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
        return recorder

    def start(self):
        in_speech_bf = True
        self.recorder.start_stream()
        ...

decoder = sphinx()
decoder.start()
```

Python returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "decoder.py", line 58, in <module>
        decoder.start()
    File "decoder.py", line 28, in start
        self.recorder.start_stream()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'start_stream'
```

PyAudio works normally when I'm not using class and methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes and methods share the same namesapce. You need to give different names for them.

And if you want to make a attribute or reference the attribute, you need to qualify the attribute with `self.`, otherwise, it became local variable.

```
from pyaudio import *

class sphinx:

    def __init__(self, samprate=16000):
        self.init(samprate)  # renamed the method

    def init(self, samprate):  # renamed the method
        audio = PyAudio()
        self.recorder = audio.open(rate=samprate, channels=1,  # qualify attribute
                                   format=paInt16, input=True,
                                   frames_per_buffer=1024)
        return self.recorder

    def start(self):
        in_speech_bf = True
        self.recorder.start_stream()
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling your recorder function, not the recorder function output.. and your recorder function does not have the start_stream() method..

try this:

```
def start(self):
    in_speech_bf = True
    rec = self.recorder()
    rec.start_stream()
```

Comment: Or simply: `self.recorder().start_stream()`